# Can you place a variable in command line

Tags: php, command-line

I have a command running in cron

```
sudo snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -0Xsq 10.0.0.98 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2> textfile
```

10.0.0.98 is a variable and i would like whichever value is placed there to be read in a php script and posted with the command results. Is this possible and if so, how can i achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Look at '-r' on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

You can set your variable and then run an 'include' or 'require'.